# How to get unchecked multiple checkboxes values in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need a jQuery selector to fetch all the checkboxes in a page. I've got no results so far. Can anyone give me the right selector please?
My jquery code:

```
function show_MemberCheckboxes(vall) {
    alert(vall);
    if($('#status_chechk_'+vall).is(':checked')){
        $('input:checkbox[name=subject_'+vall+']').attr('checked',true);
        var arr = [];
        i = 0;    
        $('#subject_'+vall+':checked').each(function(){
            arr[i++] = $(this).val();
        });        
        alert(arr);
    }
    else {
        var arrr = [];
        i = 0;    
        $('#subject_'+vall+'not:checked').each(function(){
            arr[i++] = $(this).val();
        });        
        alert(arrr);
        $('input:checkbox[name=subject_'+vall+']').attr('checked',false);
    }
}
```

My first checkbox code:

`<input type="checkbox" name="status_chechk" id="status_chechk_<?php echo $i;?>" value="" onclick="show_MemberCheckboxes('<?php echo $i; ?>');"/>`

my other check boxes loop,actually I want to get these checkboxes values.

`<input type="checkbox" name="subject_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $posts_1->id; ?>" id="subject_<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="show_SubjectCheckboxes('<?php echo $i; ?>');"
 <?php if (in_array($posts_1->id, $array) AND in_array($date, $datearr)){ echo 'CHECKED';} ?>`

Comment: please post HTML example that you work on...

Comment: I want to get value of checkbox if it is not checked,

Comment: It's amazing someone vote down my question,I am in serious problem,

Comment: Serious problems require clear communication and serious effort on your part to enable us to more effectively help you with our volunteered time.  The question was very possibly down voted because someone felt that it was unclear.  The posted code will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your code, try this:

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)")
```

Comment: I want to get value of checkbox if it is not checked

Comment: as suggested by @karl Anderson
You will get the value of the all unchecked checkboxs from the above code
change input to or checkbox name ;)